# Emacs regexp to search lines containing multiple occurrences of a word

Tags: regex, emacs

I am trying to understand whether regexp search can be used to search for lines that contain a certain word multiple times.

For example, I would like to find the line below because it contain twice the word Cable

```
<Connection Action="New" ID="277766368412" From="Cable:25425374" FromPosition="84" To="Cable:25389991" ToPosition="12"></Connection>
```

What should my regexp look like?

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should clarify the question, because the way it is,
the obvious `"Cable.*Cable"` works.

Maybe you want references, they work as well: `"\\(Cable\\).*\\1"`.

Just in case you didn't know before `re-builder` is a nice tool.
Just paste your string into a buffer and experiment with `re-builder`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Is it also possible to find out a count of matches?

Comment: `re-builder` displays the number of matches in the minibuffer

Answer (score 2):

Something like `\<\(.*\)\>.*\1` should work, although you might want to have a more restrictive pattern inside the capturing parenteses; the current one doesn't attempt to restrict the matched pattern to a single "word" but you could change the dot to e.g. `[A-Za-z]` if that's a suitable "word" definition for you.